# How to attach VC++ debugger (or gdb) in this situation?

Tags: visual-c++, gdb, debugging

I'm running a typical producer and consumer process, but they are executed by using pipe in the command line like the following:

`c:\>producer | consumer`

`producer` is just printing out data to `stdout`, and `consumer` reads from `stdin`.

My problem is that I want to debug `consumer` process. What is the best way to do it in both VC++ and gdb?

One solution is dumping out into a file and reading the file:

```
c:\>producer > temp.data
c:\>consumer < temp.data
```

However, the amount of data communicated by the two is extremely large. `temp.data` would be more than 1TB! I may use compression, but it takes huge amount of time for just compressing/uncompressing. So, I want to do it online.

Current my workaround is:

1. Put a sleep function (e.g., sleeping 10 seconds) in the main function of `consumer` before doing any job such as reading from `stdin`.
2. Invoke `producer | consumer` from the console. Then, `consumer` is started with a 10-second-sleep.
3. Attach `consumer` process by VC++ and gdb in 10 seconds.
4. Okay, after the sleep, I can now debug the consumer.

Yes, this workaround is working. But, it's pretty annoying. I guess there is a better way to debug in this situation. I appreciate any idea for it.

Comment: Is the producer output static? I.e. can you do C:\> consumer < produceroutput.txt

Comment: Good point. I updated my question.

Comment: That's a pretty good workaround, not sure why you need a better solution?

Comment: Thanks, but I need to switch some windows, and must manually attach debugger in 10 seconds or whatever time. I just wonder if there is a simple debugging step as if debugging a single process instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two solutions come to mind

Change your sleep to be

```
// this waits indefinitely without killing the CPU
while(true) {SleepEx(100, FALSE);}
```

Once you attach the debugee manually you just put a break point on the sleep and then you can jump out of the loop manually.

or better yet (unless its a service/process with no UI access) add a [DebugBreak](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679297(VS.85).aspx) statement where the Sleep is instead. This will cause the an exception to be thrown and you will be prompted to kill the process or debug launching your default debugger on the system..

```
DebugBreak();
```